# How to compare value selected by user in HTML table and value stored in array of object

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, html-table, comparison

let user select data from the dropdown in HTML table cell and compare it with an array of objects and prompt some message based on the decision. 
I have an array of objects:

```
const tabledata = [
  {
    name: "George Clooney",
    keyUnit: "Clooney",
    unit2: "George",
    unit3: "",
  },
  {
    name: "George A. Clooney",
    keyUnit: "Clooney",
    unit2: "George",
    unit3: "A",
  },
  {
    name: "George Allan Clooney",
    keyUnit: "Clooney",
    unit2: "George",
    unit3: "Allan",
  },
  {
    name: "George Robert Clooney",
    keyUnit: "Clooney",
    unit2: "George",
    unit3: "Robert",
  },
  {
    name: "Simon Cowell",
    keyUnit: "Cowell",
    unit2: "Simon",
    unit3: "",
  },
];
```

I am creating data based on this.
***I firstly want the user to select data from the dropdown in the table cell and want to compare it with the above array of objects if it's matched then prompt all answers are correct else wrong.***

```js
const tabledata = [{
    name: "George Clooney",
    keyUnit: "Clooney",
    unit2: "George",
    unit3: "",
  },
  {
    name: "George A. Clooney",
    keyUnit: "Clooney",
    unit2: "George",
    unit3: "A",
  },
  {
    name: "George Allan Clooney",
    keyUnit: "Clooney",
    unit2: "George",
    unit3: "Allan",
  },
  {
    name: "George Robert Clooney",
    keyUnit: "Clooney",
    unit2: "George",
    unit3: "Robert",
  },
  {
    name: "Simon Cowell",
    keyUnit: "Cowell",
    unit2: "Simon",
    unit3: "",
  },
];
let headers = ["name", "key Unit", "unit2", "unit3"];
const generateTable = (tableID) => {
  let selectedTable = document.querySelector(`#${tableID}`);
  let table = document.createElement("table");
  table.classList.add("table");
  table.classList.add("custom");
  let headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
  headers.forEach((headerText) => {
    let header = document.createElement("th");
    let textNode = document.createTextNode(headerText);
    header.appendChild(textNode);
    headerRow.appendChild(header);
  });
  table.appendChild(headerRow);

  tabledata.forEach((data) => {
    let row = document.createElement("tr");
    Object.values(data).forEach((text) => {
      let cell = document.createElement("td");
      let textNode = document.createTextNode(text);
      cell.appendChild(textNode);
      row.appendChild(cell);
    });
    table.appendChild(row);
  });
  selectedTable.appendChild(table);
};

generateTable("table1");
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="table-responsive" id="table1">
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.3/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

[image: EXPECTED OUTPUT]

Answer (score 0):

```js
const tabledata = [{
    name: "George Clooney",
    keyUnit: "Clooney",
    unit2: "George",
    unit3: "",
  },
  {
    name: "George A. Clooney",
    keyUnit: "Clooney",
    unit2: "George",
    unit3: "A",
  },
  {
    name: "George Allan Clooney",
    keyUnit: "Clooney",
    unit2: "George",
    unit3: "Allan",
  },
  {
    name: "George Robert Clooney",
    keyUnit: "Clooney",
    unit2: "George",
    unit3: "Robert",
  },
  {
    name: "Simon Cowell",
    keyUnit: "Cowell",
    unit2: "Simon",
    unit3: "",
  },
];
const tableOptions = [{
    id: 0,
    option1: "George",
    option2: "Clooney",
    option3: "",
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    option1: "George",
    option2: "A",
    option3: "Clooney"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    option1: "George",
    option2: "Allan",
    option3: "Clooney"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    option1: "George",
    option2: "Robert",
    option3: "Clooney"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    option1: "Simon",
    option2: "Cowell",
    option3: ""
  },
];
const answers = [
  "Clooney",
  "George",
  "empty",
  "Clooney",
  "George",
  "A",
  "Clooney",
  "George",
  "Allan",
  "Clooney",
  "George",
  "Robert",
  "Cowell",
  "Simon",
  "empty",
];
let headers = ["name", "key Unit", "unit2", "unit3"];
const generateTable = (tableID) => {
  let selectedTable = document.querySelector(`#${tableID}`);
  let table = document.createElement("table");
  table.classList.add("table");
  table.classList.add("custom");
  let headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
  headers.forEach((headerText) => {
    let header = document.createElement("th");
    let textNode = document.createTextNode(headerText);
    header.appendChild(textNode);
    headerRow.appendChild(header);
  });
  table.appendChild(headerRow);

  tabledata.forEach((data) => {
    let row = document.createElement("tr");
    Object.values(data).forEach((text) => {
      let cell = document.createElement("td");
      let textNode = document.createTextNode(text);
      cell.appendChild(textNode);
      row.appendChild(cell);
    });
    table.appendChild(row);
  });
  selectedTable.appendChild(table);
};
// generateTable("table1");

const createTable = (tableID) => {
  const names = tabledata.map((data) => {
    return data.name;
  });
  let selectedTable = document.querySelector(`#${tableID}`);
  const createdTable = document.createElement("table");
  const tableHeader = document.createElement("thead");
  const tableBody = document.createElement("tbody");
  createdTable.classList.add("table");
  createdTable.classList.add("custom");
  headers.forEach((headerVal) => {
    const th = document.createElement("th");
    const thVal = document.createTextNode(headerVal);
    th.appendChild(thVal);
    tableHeader.appendChild(th);
  });
  names.forEach((name) => {
    const tr = document.createElement("tr");
    tr.classList.add("customRow");
    const td = document.createElement("td");
    const val = document.createTextNode(name);
    td.appendChild(val);
    tr.appendChild(td);
    tableBody.appendChild(tr);
  });
  createdTable.appendChild(tableHeader);
  createdTable.appendChild(tableBody);
  selectedTable.appendChild(createdTable);
  const customRows = document.querySelectorAll(".customRow");
  const bringOptions = (i, row) => {
    tableOptions.forEach((option) => {
      if (option.id === i) {
        const td = document.createElement("td");
        const select = document.createElement("select");
        select.id = i;
        Object.values(option).forEach((vals) => {
          if (typeof vals != "number") {
            const option = document.createElement("option");
            const optionVal = document.createTextNode(vals);
            if (optionVal.data == "") {
              option.value = "empty";
            } else {
              option.value = optionVal.data;
            }
            option.appendChild(optionVal);
            select.append(option);
          }
          td.appendChild(select);
          row.appendChild(td);
        });
      }
    });
  };
  customRows.forEach((row, i) => row.classList.add(i));
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    customRows.forEach((row, i) => {
      bringOptions(i, row);
    });
  }
};

createTable("table1");
var selectedAnswer = [{}];
const checkButton = document.querySelector("#checkAnswer");
checkButton.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  selectedAnswer = [];
  const targetTableId = checkButton.getAttribute("data-tragetable");
  const table = document.querySelector(`#${targetTableId}`);
  const selectedTableRow = document.querySelectorAll(
    `#${targetTableId} .customRow`
  );
  selectedTableRow.forEach((row) => {
    const selectGroup = row.querySelectorAll("select");
    selectGroup.forEach((select) => {
      selectedAnswer.push(select.value);
    });
  });
  if (JSON.stringify(selectedAnswer) === JSON.stringify(answers)) {
    alert("correct");
  } else {
    alert("try again!!");
  }
});

const showAnswerButton = document.querySelector("#showAnswer");
showAnswerButton.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  const targetTableId = checkButton.getAttribute("data-tragetable");
  const table = document.querySelector(`#${targetTableId}`);
  const selectedTableRow = document.querySelectorAll(
    `#${targetTableId} .customRow`
  );
  const select = table.querySelectorAll("select");
  select.forEach((select, i) => {
    select.value = answers[i];
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="table-responsive" id="table1">
        </table>
        <button id="checkAnswer" data-tragetable="table1">check answer</button>
        <button id="showAnswer" data-tragetable="table1">show Answer</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.3/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).